# Manually mapping with Realm for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, serialization, realm

I'm using Realm to Deserialize JSON and create an entity.

To deserialize from JSON: the name of the property in the JSON must be identical to the property name of my class. I would like to manually map so that the names can be different, is it possible?

Example of JSON:

{
"Text":"hello"
}

Example of Class:

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* myText;

I want to map "Text" with "myText".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to convert the data that is being input into Realm if your models don't line up exactly with the json response. There are a few libraries like [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) and [Realm-JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON) that help with this.
The latter has been used by the community to handle these kinds of situations. Also [here's a tutorial](https://realm.io/news/tutorial-mantle-realm/) that was written recently on mantle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Instead of creating the Realm objects directly from JSON dictionaries, create an empty Realm object and fill all it's properties as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Your model will look just like this.

```
#import "RLMObject+JSON.h"

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONInboundMappingDictionary {
return @{
         @"Text": @"myText"
         };
}

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONOutboundMappingDictionary {
return @{
         @"myText": @"Text"
         };
}
```